# useRef to focus specific input element when there are multiple input elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using React, the parent component prints out child components, each time creating multiple inputs inside the parent. When you update the input, I'm updating some state, the child is re-rendering loses the focus on the input.

Is there a way to keep the focus after re-rendering?

I try using the id of the input element, not working:

```
    const ref: any = useRef();
            
            useEffect(() => {
                    if (ref.current) {
                        ref.current[fixture.id].focus();
                    }
                }, []);
            
return (
            <input
               id={fixture.id}
               ref={ref}
               type="number"
               value={home}
               onChange={handleChangeHome}
               min={0}
               max={10}
            />
    
    )
```

Remember there are multiple input elements so when I just do:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.focus();
        }
    }, []);
```

The focus defaults to the last input field after component is rendered

Comment: How to refer to multiple elements with a ref is outlined in the [docs](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback)

Answer (score -1):

To maintain focus on an input element in a child component after it re-renders due to state updates in the parent component, you can follow these steps:

Use a unique identifier for each input element.
Store refs for each input element in an object or array.
Update the focus on the input element using its ref after each render.

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({ fixture, home, handleChangeHome }) => {
  const inputRefs = useRef({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRefs.current[fixture.id]) {
      inputRefs.current[fixture.id].focus();
    }
  });

  return (
    <input
      id={fixture.id}
      ref={el => (inputRefs.current[fixture.id] = el)}
      type="number"
      value={home}
      onChange={handleChangeHome}
      min={0}
      max={10}`enter code here`
    />
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {

  return (
    <div>
   
      {fixtures.map(fixture => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={fixture.id}
          fixture={fixture}
          home={home}
          handleChangeHome={handleChangeHome}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```